# Retrofit conversion to unicode when using POST command

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I am currently using a data class to build the request body of the retrofit POST api call.
The body is essentially containing Strings. However, I notice an issue when sending the string. Retrofit is modifying some charactere. basically my string is `Hgjdwwk=` but the logcat shows that retrofit send `Hgjdwwk\u003d`. It's converting my char to a unicode format. I need to keep it as is.

below is the data class:

```
data class RetrofitRequestBody(
    @field:com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("item")
    val item: RetrofitBodyItem?
)

data class RetrofitBodyItem(
    @field:com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id") val id: String?,
    @field:com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("key") val key: String?,
)
```

And the API call looks like this:

```
fun postCheckItem(
        data: DataItem) {
...
val response = api.postCheckItem(
                    RetrofitRequestBody(
                        item = RetrofitBodyItem(
                            id = data.challenge,
                            key = data.publicKey,
                        )
                    )
                )

....
```

The Service associated looks like:

```
    @POST("v1/check-item")
    suspend fun postCheckItem(
        @Body request: RetrofitRequestBody,
    ): Response
```

Also as I am using `Dagger-Hilt`, I have to declare the component for the data injection as below:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
class APIModule {
...

@Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("default")
    fun provideDefaultOkHttpClient() = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .build()
    } else {
        OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("auth")
    fun provideAuthOkHttpClient(
        @Named("default") okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        authInterceptor: AuthInterceptor
    ) = okHttpClient.newBuilder()
        .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
        .build()

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(
        @Named("auth") okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
    ): Retrofit {
        val gson = GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL + BuildConfig.ENDPOINT_VERSION)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }
```

I was thinking that :

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
```

will do the trick but it's not working.

Anything I miss ??
Thanks

Comment: Yes `disableHtmlEscaping()` should solve this; maybe there is some other problem with your code that it does not use this `GsonBuilder` (or even this `Retrofit` instance) in the first place? As side note: The Unicode escape in the JSON data does not affect in any way the represented data, it might only be a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Are you able to find any solution for this?